# Django-tables2 URL Link from multiple foreign key not working

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm working on a site using Django and need help with data flow and accessing the foreign key data.

**models.py**

```
class Boards(models.Model):
    board_no = models.CharField('Board No', max_length=10, unique=True)
    board_name = models.CharField('Board Name', max_length=100)

class BoardLocations(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Boards, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='board')
    location_code = models.CharField('Location Code', max_length=10, null=True)

class BoardContacts(models.Model):
    board_location = models.ForeignKey(BoardLocations, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_first_name = models.CharField('Contact First Name', max_length=100, null=True)
    contact_last_name = models.CharField('Contact Last Name', max_length=100, null=True)
```

The BoardContacts are tied to a BoardLocation which all come from a Board. I'm displaying the list of BoardContacts properly through a django-tables2 as follows:

[List of Contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Zhc.png)

The URL shows:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/adm/boards/view_data_contact_list/6/
```

where 6 is Board.id. All fine. The Contact First Name link is defined as:

**tables.py**

```
class BoardContactsTableView(tables.Table):
    selection = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor='id')
    contact_first_name = tables.LinkColumn('view_board_contact', args=[A('id')], attrs=TABLE_VIEW_ATTRS)
    contact_last_name = tables.LinkColumn('view_board_contact', args=[A('id')], attrs=TABLE_VIEW_ATTRS)

    class Meta:
        model = BoardContacts
        template_name = TABLE_TEMPLATE_NAME
        attrs = TABLE_ATTRIBUTES
        ordering = ['contact_last_name']
        fields = ('selection', 'contact_first_name', 'contact_last_name', 'contact_type', 'access_type', 'last_login', 'create_date')
```

When I select Contact First Name or Last Name, the URL changes to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/adm/boards/view_data_contact/29/
```

because source indicates:

```
<td ><a class="text-decoration-none fw-bold" style="color:gray" href="/adm/boards/view_data_contact/29/">Robert</a></td>
```

But 29 is the BoardContacts.id. I need to maintain the Board.id of 6 within the URL so I can go back to the list of contacts using the Board Contacts button on the web page. Ideally, it should look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/adm/boards/view_data_contact/6/29/
```

So, how do I make changes to LinkColumn within tables.py to include 6 and 29?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering as a LinkColumn, you can use a regular Column and build the full url in a render function.

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods

```
def render_contact_first_name(self, record, value):
    url = reverse("view_board_contact", args=(record.board_location.board.id, record.id))
    return mark_safe(f'<a href="{url}">{value}</a>')
```